# Add a REST API as data source in powerBI with Basic auth

Tags: rest, powerbi, basic-authentication, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to add a REST API to my powerBI report as a data source. The API uses Basic authentication. However, I don't want to keep my token in an unencrypted form in the query editor.
Currently, I am able to make it work by using the following in `Advanced Query Editor` with Anonymous authentication:

```
let
    token = "apiKey",
    options = [Headers=[Authorization="Basic " & token]],
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api-url/api/v1/application", options))
in
    Source
```

However, I am trying to use a method, so that I can put my `apiKey` in the data source credentials, and eventually keep this value as private.

1. Either as basic auth
   [image]
2. Or as web API key
   [image]